# how to make a slider for image such that the text below it in the next section also change using html and css?

Tags: javascript, html

I can make a slider using HTML and javascript for images but is unable to create a slider such that the text in the box below the image also change when I slide the image using the javascript and HTML

**p.s please explain with the code**

```
         <div>     
         <div class="23">   
           <img class="mySlides1" src="img_snowtops.jpg" style="width:100%">
           <img class="mySlides1" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
       <img class="mySlides1" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides1" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
     <div class="23">
     <img class="mySlides2" src="img_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides2" src="img_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <img class="mySlides2" src="img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
     </div>
      <button class="left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="-right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>
      </div>
       <script>
      var slideIndex = [1,1];
     var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2"]
      showDivs(1, 0);
      showDivs(1, 1);
      function plusDivs(n, no) {
      showDivs(slideIndex[no] += n, no)
       }
      function showDivs(n, no) {
        var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
       if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
       if (n < 1) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none"; 
     }
     x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
    }
     </script>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, - the short answer is, to make not just the image slide, - but to make an entire `<div>` slide (and all the content inside it). But there are a billion different versions of these Content Sliders, which argues the fact that there are a billion version of doing this.

I personally use the one baked into Bootstrap - [The Carousel Slider](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/).

But [The Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) are quite minimalistic and easy to implement, if you're not using a framework. [Like this](https://codepen.io/swetankrathi/pen/OyRZxL).

Comment: actually i just want to make it slide using html and javascript only without using any framework

Comment: Then I'd look at the Slick-slider example. That is not a framework, - that's a library. If you want to make a content slider from the ground-up, using vanilla-javascript; then you're pretty far from a result. That's like if you want to make a house and you have a wood and bricks and then ask: 'Now what?'. =)